# ASP.Net Web API 2 controller action timing out with IIS Express when returning custom response body with non-zero content length

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I'm experiencing a really strange issue with ASP.Net Web API 2. I have a single action (amongst my other controller actions) that returns a plain text response, and I noticed today that it was timing out, which is strange given that it's just a simple plain text response.

I do NOT experience this issue when I return a response back via a standard IHttpActionResult method, through which a relevant media formatter handles the response.

Note that the timeout is in the response returned *after* the action finishes. There is no timeout occurring anywhere in my entire code path as best I can tell; it's getting stuck somewhere after I pass things back to the framework. I tested using HTTPie (or cURL under the hood if you like), and tested with Fiddler to verify, and saw that the response headers are being returned, but that the response is getting stuck as soon as it has to send a body with a non-zero length:

```
D:\Dev> http get http://localhost:54539

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 07 Jul 2014 09:45:35 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcRHJvcGJveFxXb3JrXFByb2plY3RzXEJyb3dzZXJGcm9udFxCcm93c2VyRnJvbnQuQXBp?=

http: error: timeout: timed out
```

The original version of my controller method looks like this:

```
protected IHttpActionResult PlainText(string message)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

I couldn't see any issue with this, and it has (regularly) worked at some point in the past. Just not now for some reason.

As part of debugging, I changed it to this, and it worked:

```
protected IHttpActionResult PlainText(string message)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

For some reason, the zero length response body allows the response to complete. If I put a single character in that string though, the response will timeout as soon as it tried to send the body.

I'm pretty sure my next attempt is what StringContent does under the hood, but I figured I'd try it manually anyway:

```
protected IHttpActionResult PlainText(string message)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        writer.Write(message);
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
    }
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

As expected, I get a timeout after the headers have been sent. If I change it to a zero byte array, or just don't write to the stream, I get a zero length content body and it sends.

I have also tried an equivalent of the above using StreamContent, with pretty much the same results. I have even tried using PushStreamContent with a delegate (tried both async and non-async) to push the contents back manually, and there were no issues writing to the response stream or closing it, but the response still times out once the headers have been received.

One last thing I looked at was a comparison of the response headers between a normal (working) JSON response and my failing custom plain-text response, and the only thing of note I could see was a Content-Length header included in the JSON response that worked. I have tried manually specifying the Content-Length header in all of my attempts above as a test to see if this might be related to the problem, but for some reason that particular header is never received. I don't have an explanation for this.

What could possibly cause arbitrary custom responses to time out like this? Undoubtedly I've introduced something somewhere in my code but for the life of me I can't see what it might be...

**EDIT**

I have created an additional project to self-host my Web API project via OWIN and the problem does not occur. I have also tried pointing *full* IIS at it, and that works fine too. This leads me to believe the problem is somehow related to IIS Express.

**EDIT 2**

I am absolutely stumped. I've tried rebooting, repairing IIS Express and also reinstalling it, all to no avail. I absolutely can't get it to return a custom plain text response.

Comment: what is the version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` package that you are using?

Comment: @KiranChalla Hi, sorry for the slow reply. I'm using 5.2.0.

Comment: @KiranChalla Worth noting I was on 5.1 when I first noticed the problem, but in creating the OWIN project to test this, I inadvertantly created it with 5.2, so I upgraded my other projects to 5.2 as well. The problem occurs for me on both versions though.